# Why did the guru tell Aang he needs to stop feeling "earthly attachments" to enter the Avatar State?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender

It seems like the guru's rule of no Earthly attachments (or not loving anyone) was only valid at the end of book 2. Past avatars, like Roku and Kuruk, were both fully capable of entering the Avatar State while being in love. Aang himself masters the Avatar State while loving Katara, as shown in the Legend of Korra and even more so in the comics. The guru clearly said the Avatar State is impossible as long as there is an Earthly attachment. Was he really saying that the Avatar needs to learn how to "switch off" love temporarily in order to enter the Avatar State?

Answer (score 1):

The guru (which was definitely not Laghima) that Aang spoke with was not saying that he is not allowed to love someone. He is saying that you need to be able to let the ones you love go if you need to.
Aang does this in the fight with Azula in the crystal caves when he realizes what it meant.

This is further backed up in LOK when Zaheer talks about Guru Laghima's teachings. He says you must "let go of your earthly tether" in order to be able to fly with air bending.
After Zaheers partner Pi-Li dies he does exactly this and is able to fly away with Korra.

Answer (score -1):

Earthly attachment is not about loving anyone; actually loving someone is not earthly at all.

Earthly attachments are about material attachments: Selfishness, pride, etc.

Comment: I think the show was pretty strongly implying that loving someone is the basis of "earthly attachment".

Comment: @tphilli you are wrong in assuming that, specially seeing as loving is a requisite to open the fourth chackra.

Comment: @tphilli loving isn't the attachment. Aang not being willing to let her go is the attachment.

Comment: This answer could be improved by going into it a little more; adding some information from these comments above mine would be a good way to start.

Comment: the guru is guru lahiema lol

Comment: @MarvelBoy Its clearly stated multiple times that loving someone is an earthly attachment. You don't have to stop loving them but you have to be able to "Let them go" if you need to. In LOK this is backed up further when Zaheer learns to fly after his partner Pi-Li is killed and he "Lets go of his earthly tether" and then can fly.